# node.js - redirect to another url in middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my **MEAN SPA** application, I want to redirect all url request to **index** with additional parameters. For example, when user type `http://localhost:3003/`, it should call **index page**. When user type `http://localhost:3003/game/playstation/ps4`, it also should call **index page**, with extra parameters like `game, palystation, ps4`, but It redirect to **index** without extra parameters. My Code is given below:

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // get the url without main domain address
    var original_url =  req.originalUrl;

    // convert string url to array
    var url_part = original_url.split('/');

    // remove first array, bcz first is always ''
    url_part.shift();

    // check if url is main url request without any parameter
    if( url_part[0] !== '' ) {
        // if not, then store all url_part array
        req.request_url = url_part;

        // redirct to main '/' call
        // when it redirect to main url, then req.request is empty
        res.redirect('/');
     }

    next();
});

app.get('/', function( req, res) {
     // here req.request_url is always 'undefined'
     console.log("req.request_url : ", req.request_url);

      return res.render('index.ejs', {
         url: req.request_url
      });
});
```

**EDIT**

I have to redirect to **index** route not any others, because in my **SPA** application, I just load my **index** route with default **js, css and others**, and all others will be call from **api**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the function handling index, does `req` contain a empty `request_url`? Or is there no member `request_url`? Can you show the index handler?

Comment: request_url is always 'undefined'

Comment: `app.get('/', req, res) {` should be `app.get('/', function (req, res) {`, and you forgot a `);`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this and both will map to the same function but will have the parameters set or null if it maps from the '/' route

```
var indexPageFunc = function(res, req){
  var type = req.param('type'); // game or null
  var system = req.param('system'); // playstation or null
  var version = req.param('version'); // ps4 or null
  res.render('index.ejs');
}
app.get('/', indexPageFunc);
app.get('/:type/:system/:version, indexPageFunc);
```

Comment: `var version = req.param('type');` should be `var version = req.param('version');`. Also, you should precise it will keep the parameters in the URL. +1 for mentionning you can get the parameters this way thought. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Correct! Edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it in that way. Redirect send 302 to browser, and user make new separate request to your server.

You can just return same response for all routes

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    // get the url without main domain address
    var original_url =  req.originalUrl;

    // convert string url to array
    var url_part = original_url.split('/');

    // remove first array, bcz first is always ''
    url_part.shift();

    res.render('index.ejs', {
        url: url_part
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: redirect to another URL and include GET parameters.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var url_part = req.originalUrl.split('/');
    console.log('' + req.originalUrl + ' => ' + url_part);
    url_part.shift();
    if( url_part[0] !== '' ) {
        //You could add as GET parameters, but it will be shown to the user
        res.redirect('/?request_url=' + url_part);
     }

    next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     // here req.request_url is always 'undefined'
     console.log("req.request_url : ", req.request_url);

      return res.json({
         url: req.request_url
      });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Or you'll have to find a way to rewrite the URL, and do a POST request.